# count the occurances of elements in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this, I want to `count` the frequency of each element

```
var arr = [1, 5, 7, -1];
function countArray (arr){
    var map = [];
    for (var i =0; i < arr.length ; i++){
        map[arr[i]]++;
    }
    console.log(map);  
}
```

The `console.log` prints `[1: NaN, 5: NaN, 7: NaN, -1: NaN]`

I expected it to print `[1: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1, -1: 1]`

I do not understand why I'm getting `NaN`

Comment: Before doing `++`, you need to initialize the values to `0`. Otherwise, you're doing `null+1`, which is NaN (not a number). You can solve this by adding that at the beginning of your `for` loop: `if(!map.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])){ map[arr[i]] = 0; }`

Comment: @JoshKG  I'm a single mom learning programming.

Comment: Sorry, bad "Lego Movie" joke :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if it was the first occurance, then you would try to increment an undefined. So first check if it is undefined then assign 0, or increment it.

And you should use an Object, not an array. The object has a `key` and `value` whereas an `Array` is an ordered set of elements, accessed by their numeric index.

I'm  editing this to explain that you *can* use an `Array` Object. If the value of the index is greater than largest index in the array, then it will be resized. However, I think an Object is better to use because in the future if you use some other type of key, (not a Number) then the code won't need any changes.

```
var arr = [1, 5, 7, -1];
function countArray (arr) {
    var map = {};
    for ( var i =0; i < arr.length ; i++ ){
        map[ arr[i] ] = typeof map[ arr[i] ]  === 'undefined' ? 1 : ++map[ arr[i] ];
    }
    console.log(map);  
}
```

Comment: Alternatively: `map[arr[i]] = (map[arr[i]]  || 0 ) + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is fine but you can do it with array.reduce one liner:

```js
var arr = [1, 5, 7, -1, 1,1];

var r = arr.reduce((ac, x) => { if (!ac[x]) ac[x] = 0;  return ac[x]++, ac},{});

document.write(JSON.stringify(r))
```

choose whatever you find more readable..

Comment: I just put my one-liner here so yours wouldn't be alone: `xs.reduce((acc, x) => Object.assign(acc, { [x]: (acc[x] || 0) + 1 }), {});`

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, please use ES5 syntax when answering questions like that, for maximum browser compatibility. Arrow functions (introduced with ECMAScript 2015) are not supported by all major browsers yet (IE 11, for example, which is the highest version of IE available on Windows 7, is still widely used).

Answer (score 2):

A more [explanatory version (JSBin)](https://jsbin.com/xohuxu/1/edit?js,console) with reduce:

```
var arr = [1, 5, 7, -1];    

var count = arr.reduce(function(obj, next) {
  obj[next] = ++obj[next] || 1;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if array already contains key, you can use "in" to do that.

```
var arr = [1, 5, 7, -1, -1];
function countArray (arr){
    var map = [];
    for (var i =0; i < arr.length ; i++){
        if (arr[i] in map) map[arr[i]]++;
        else map[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
    console.log(map);  
}
countArray (arr)
```

Output:

> [1: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1, -1: 2]

Comment: This will cause problems if an element is used that matches the name of a property in the Object prototype. If you're using `in`, you should filter the results by doing a `hasOwnProperty` check. I also can't recommend following the "inline" style of your conditionals given the OP is just learning.